# Why is the requestAnimationFrame callback task taking so long?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, google-chrome-devtools, requestanimationframe

I'm making a game and failing to achieve 60fps despite the game logic/rendering well within the necessary budget. The typical budget for 60fps is ~10-12ms due to browser overhead. If you look that this screenshot, the task responsible for executing the rAF callback is excessively longer than the callback itself.

[image: frame performance]

The code is fairly simple, looping over ~100 items that draw hexagon tiles to the canvas using CanvasRenderingContext2D. I've eliminated all calls to save/restore for perf.

If someone can explain why the time between the small purple slice `Update Layer Tree` and the green slice at the end of the task `Composite Layers` is taking so long, that would help. Or if anyone has any tips/tricks for performance with rAF.

A theory I had is that I am somehow holding onto a reference within the rAF callback and that is causing it to wait??

The repo is here: https://github.com/LudicGames/arce

Update: Here is another frame screenshot with the GPU row. The GPU row shows a lot of usage, but there doesn't seem to be any way of knowing *what* that usage is. Presumably rendering the context I just wrote but why so long?

You can try to run the performance yourself here http://arce.io.

[image: frame timing]

Comment: If the code is simple,it might be possible to include it in the question? Also on your screenshot it's hard to see how long did the idle laat. Seems plausible it was just waiting the next painting frame here (~13ms later)

Comment: The user code is simple but is using libraries so its not so simple to just include here. You can see the frame time is 21.2ms (~47fps) at the top. The dotted lines on the left and right signify the frame bounds. I don't understand why the task takes so long if the code within it does not.

Comment: We still need to see what you are doing in an [MCVE] in the question itself. What do you have in the GPU row? What frame rate is your monitor set to? Can you reproduce with a simpler code [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/mvghz1xb/)?

Comment: @Kaiido you can visit arce.io to run the performance test yourself. The code is in this repo here https://github.com/LudicGames/arce. Sorry I can't provide a more minimal example but if I remove all the code, there is no problem.

Comment: just trying to figure out what could cause the rAF callback to finish in 4ms but still cause 20ms frames. very confusing.

Comment: To find out why GPU takes so long you would have to perform low-level debugging of Chrome and/or Skia. Look for info on the official chromium site or in their source code, you can also ask on https://crbug.com. P.S. Also there's a brute-force approach: recursive divide-and-conquer debugging when you remove parts of code/CSS until the problem is gone.